# Arrange and store text from function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract and arrange some words from a specific text.

```
text = '''
def function_cal(revenues_shops, surplus_margin, meadian_profit):
     meadian_profit= revenues_shops* surplus_margin
     return meadian_profit
'''

# Extract names
lines = text.split('\n')
for line in lines:
  x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
  if x != None:
      values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
      function_name = values[0]
      arguments = values[1][:-2].split(', ')

      print(f"Function Name: {function_name}")
      print(f"Arguments: {arguments}")
```

The code is shown above functioning well and produce good results with the command for print.
Now I want to store all of these results in separate files (e.g data frames, dictionaries, etc.) because I want to use these results for further analysis.

Can anybody help me how to solve this?

I tried with those lines described below but is not working

```
    # Create 
    splited_table1= dict() 
    splited_table2= dict() 
        
    # Extract 
    def extraction_variables(text):
      lines = text.split('\n')
      for line in lines:
        x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
        if x != None:
            values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
            splited_table1 = values[0]
            splited_table2 = values[1][:-2].split(', ')
            return splited_table1, splited_table2


extraction_variables(text)
    
    splited_table1.sort()
    splited_table2.sort()
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Please provide an error message or more preferably the stack trace. Also, you've not used Pandas anywhere why do you need dataframes here?

Comment: Output from the function I want to be stored in some format. Above is shown an example with dictionaries . At the end of this function, I want to see stored values. If you run this on your PC you can see that not working or in other words not store values

Comment: You're not using the values returned from the function anywhere. You don't require to initialize variables before calling the function.

Comment: The main idea is to store text to some object. If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't have sent a question. I disagree with your remarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you've not used the value returned from inside the `extraction_variables` function. To do so, your code would look something like:

```py
import re

text = '''
def function_cal(revenues_shops, surplus_margin, meadian_profit):
     meadian_profit= revenues_shops* surplus_margin
     return meadian_profit
'''


def extraction_variables(text):
    # initialize the return variables *inside* the function
    splited_table1, splited_table2 = dict(), dict()
    lines = text.split('\n')
        for line in lines:
            x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
            if x is not None:
                values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
                splited_table1 = values[0]
                splited_table2 = values[1][:-2].split(', ')
                return splited_table1, splited_table2


splited_table1, splited_table2 = extraction_variables(text)
splited_table1  # => 'function_cal'
splited_table2  # => ['revenues_shops', 'surplus_margin', 'meadian_profit']
```